# CSS- Responsive full width grid of square divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a grid of square divs. This is what I tried:

HTML:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    width:50vw;
    height:50vw;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
}
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfwm674c/))

But instead of getting two columns, the divs display one below the other..

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `50vw` as the scrollbar is not included in the calculations. Use 50% instead.

There is a *very* slight difference but it's  one that your users are unlikely to notice.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50vw;
  float: left;
}
#a {
  background-color: red;
}
#b {
  background-color: blue;
}
#c {
  background-color: green;
}
#d {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">A</div>
<div id="b">B</div>
<div id="c">C</div>
<div id="d">D</div>
```