# CSS grid of square div elements that fills width but not height

Tags: html, css

My goal is to create a grid of square "pixels" (div elements) that automatically scales the pixels to match the width of the page (up to `max-width: 800px`).

I want to implement this using CSS in a way that is "agnostic" to the number of rows and columns in the grid. This rules out using CSS `display: grid`, for example.

Here is my attempt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pixel grid</title>
    <style>
        #container {
            max-width: 800px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            gap: 8px;
        }

        .pixel-row {
            display: flex;
            gap: 8px;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .pixel {
            flex: 1;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>

    <!-- Script to generate row and column elements-->
    <script>
        // These numbers could change
        const rows = 10;
        const columns = 14;

        for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            newRow = document.createElement("div");
            newRow.classList.add("pixel-row");
            for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                newPixel = document.createElement("div");
                newPixel.classList.add("pixel");
                newRow.appendChild(newPixel);
            }
            document.getElementById("container").appendChild(newRow);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see in the following screenshot, this achieves the desired distribution of columns. But I cannot figure out how to make the height of the pixel `div`s match their width.

[image: Screengrab of rendered page, showing correct spacing of columns but incorrect]

**How do I style the `.pixel`s and `.pixel-row`s so that the pixels have height matching their width?**

#### Disclaimers

- I have seen various tutorials online for making these kinds of equally spaced pixel grids, but all of them were one step away from my specific problem, e.g. because they used a static number of rows/columns (meaning they could use `display: grid` or `display: flexbox` with `flex-wrap`), or used a static pixel size (`.pixel { width: 10px; height: 10px; }`)
- For example, my question is distinct from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58114328/css-responsive-grid-of-squares) because I only want the *width* of the grid to fit in the browser. If there are many rows, then the user should have to scroll vertically to see them.
- And my question is distinct from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461684/css-responsive-full-width-grid-of-square-divs) because that solution depends on there being exactly two columns.

Comment: [`aspect-ratio: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio)?

Comment: That works like a charm! Thanks, I would never have found that on my own.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped; please feel free to post the answer to your question and - when possible - accept that answer, so the system 'knows' the question is answered. Others may offer better answers in the interim, however, so do consider those as they're posted.